# answer incoming calls automatically with Skype for Linux

Tags: skype, voip

How can Skype for Linux be set to answer incoming calls automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> opens the "Options/Preferences" dialog window.
2. Under the "Privacy" tab (2nd from above - see screenhot) you can set/activate the option:

> Automatically answer incoming calls.

The same goes for the "Video Device". Optionally:

> Start my video automatically when I am in a call.

[image]